# HTTP status 404 for image on Meta's 404 page

Tags: bug, status-completed, design, meta

Stack Exchange 404 error pages ('page not found') usually have site-specific images, like this one from the [main site](https://superuser.com/404):

[image]

However, the image on the equivalent page on the [meta site](https://meta.superuser.com/404) 404s itself; it leads to this link which is not available: https://cdn.sstatic.net/Sites/skins/sketchy/img/sketchy-404.png

[image]

Is this intended and some kind of 'recursive' joke? Other meta sites don't seem to have this, e.g. [Meta Stack Overflow](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/404) displays a waffle iron in the form of a keyboard.

Comment: RE: Stack Overflow's 404 page: [Maybe Microsoft were onto something](https://superuser.com/q/792607/107240)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you can’t find a page on Meta Super User, you will no longer find a page that can’t find the image to show (it is now using the same image as SU).

> Load page, then not found
> Error image also gone??
> No longer! [Try it](https://meta.superuser.com/404)